# Dynamically change selectbox options based on previous option selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying to accomplish is the following... 
HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link href="css/jquery.selectbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>



    <select name="dateselector_parent" id="dateselector_parent" tabindex="1">
        <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
        <option value="1">2012</option>
        <option value="1">2011</option>
        <option value="1">2010</option>
        <option value="2">Predefined Dates</option>
    </select>

    <select name="dateselector_child" id="dateselector_child" tabindex="2">
        <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
        <option value="1">January</option>
        <option value="1">February</option>
        <option value="1">March</option>
        <option value="1">April</option>
        <option value="1">May</option>
        <option value="1">June</option>
        <option value="1">July</option>
        <option value="1">August</option>
        <option value="1">September</option>
        <option value="1">October</option>
        <option value="1">November</option>
        <option value="1">December</option>
        <option value="2">Current Month</option>
        <option value="2">Month to Date</option>
        <option value="2">Last 7 Days</option>
    </select>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.selectbox-0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/datejs.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#dateselector_parent").selectbox();
        $("#dateselector_child").selectbox();
    });


    </script>
</body>
```

This creates two select boxes, I want one box to display content according to what the user chooses on the other one. For example, if the user chooses, 2010 or 2011 or 2012, I want to display Jan-Dec as options on the second one.  If the user chooses, Predefined Dates, I want to display Current Month, Month to Date, and Last 7 Days.  The javascript plugin I'm using allows the user to define the onChange, onOpen, and onClose methods.  I have been doing some research and it appears that AJAX is involved in trying to accomplish this, but since I don't know one bit of PHP I would like to know if it's possible to accomplish this with jQuery. (I have attempted to solve this problem with no luck of course, I am not looking for someone to do it for me, I just want to be pointed in the right direction, whether I can accomplish this with jQuery or if it's necessary to use AJAX since I haven't seen an example online with only jQuery).

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: I would suggest you to use two child dropdowns and show/hide based on the selection of the parent dropdown. If you remove options based on selection (as you are trying) it could lead to a security issue at the server side.

Comment: Hmm, that is certainly something I had not thought about...So the second dropdown is not visible until the user chooses a date (2010,2011 or 2012) would "show" the Jan-Dec select box, and the other one would "show" the predefined date (and Jan-Dec would remain hidden). Is this what you mean? Very nice input...thanks :)

Comment: Hey Kaf, I'm having a little trouble creating the script for show/hide, do you think you could help me out a bit?  

I created a div which contains the select box (now I have three, 2 of them are contained in their own div) and I'm trying to use .hide() to hide them when the pages loads, but I'm not getting anything. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: I still haven't been able to figure it out, any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the following work for your requirement. Having 3 child dropdowns (no divs) 1. --Select--, 2. Jan-Dec 3.Other options

```
$().ready(function () {

    var selectedOnLoad = $('#dateselector_parent').val();
    setChild(selectedOnLoad);

    $('#dateselector_parent').change(function () {
       var selectedValue = $('#dateselector_parent').val();
       setChild(selectedValue);
    });

});

function setChild(value){
    //Have your three child selector names as follows in your markup as well and assuming they are not in divs
    var arr = [ "dateselector_child_", "dateselector_child_1", "dateselector_child_2"];

    jQuery.each(arr, function() {
            if(this == "dateselector_child_" + value){
                $("#" + this).show();
            }else{
                $("#" + this).hide();
            }
     });
}
```

**UPDATE:** Adding markup for the above script

```
<select name="dateselector_parent" id="dateselector_parent" tabindex="1">
    <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
    <option value="1">2012</option>
    <option value="1">2011</option>
    <option value="1">2010</option>
    <option value="2">Predefined Dates</option>
</select>


<select name="dateselector_child_" id="dateselector_child_" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
</select>

<select name="dateselector_child_1" id="dateselector_child_1" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="1">March</option>
    <option value="1">April</option>
    <option value="1">May</option>
    <option value="1">June</option>
    <option value="1">July</option>
    <option value="1">August</option>
    <option value="1">September</option>
    <option value="1">October</option>
    <option value="1">November</option>
    <option value="1">December</option>
</select>

<select name="dateselector_child_2" id="dateselector_child_2" tabindex="2">
    <option value="">--Select Date--</option>
    <option value="2">Current Month</option>
    <option value="2">Month to Date</option>
    <option value="2">Last 7 Days</option>
</select>
```

Check the **setChild(value)** function. Parent's selected value is passing to that function when page is ready (just after loading) and also when user change the selection. Parent's selected value could be "","1","2". Next the foreach loop finds the name of the child that needs to show and others are hidden. if user select ---Select--- option of the parent then that function will show "dateselector_child_" and others two hidden.

Hope it's clear now....

Comment: This is definitely what I want and thus I will mark it as an answer, you don't have to help me any further, only if you wish to.  What's going on is that the 3 select boxes are showing, once I choose from the first child group (2012,2011,2010) another select box appears (a 4th one), same thing happens when choosing (Predefined Dates), the previous one disappears but another one appears (with the correct info). What am I doing wrong? Also, you have 3 childs, don't we just need 1 parent and 2 children? (1 children holds Jan-Dec and the other values on the other one). Thank you!

Comment: So the problem seems that it's not hiding the selecboxes when the page loads, and when it does load (based on the selection) it creates another select box (completely void of any styling I have created). That is my issue at the moment and any feedback will help a lot.

Comment: When user select **<option value="">--Select Date--</option>** of the parent it will show the 3rd child. That is why there are 3 child controls... You need to have all three as named in the array in a single container so that it will smoothly appear the required select box based on the selection. I am not sure what your issue atm..

Comment: I am confused as to what the parent and child elements will hold. I understand 2 of the child selects will hold Jan-Dec on one of them and Current Month, Month to Date and Last 7 Days on the other one. What I don't understand is the dateselector_child_ holds and dateselector_parent holds

Comment: More than clear!!!! I appreciate all of your help! Thank you so much! Now I understand what you meant. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a startingpoint!

```
$("#dateselector_parent").change(function() {
    $('#dateselector_child').val($(this).find("option:selected").index());
});
```

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jq6K4/1/)

Comment: I think he needs to remove unwanted options from child dropdown based on the selection of the parent dropdown.

Comment: Kaf is correct. How would I go about hiding the rest of the elements?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX, expands to  Asynchronous JavaScript And XML. It involves writing an `XMLHTTPRequest` to retrieve the contents from a server.

If you can store your logic (what to display when a certain option is chosen) in a few lines of code, you can embed it in JavaScript or jQuery.

So, in your case, it is not necessary to use AJAX. You can accomplish this with a bit of code in JavaScript.

"[Creating a 2 level interdependent select list](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/selectcontent2.shtml)" might help.