# Use Javascript or HTML to change form options based on previous form answers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do something like the classic form for country state city.
In such a form the country you choose determines what states are shown in the state box and the state you choose determines what cities are shown in the city box.

More specifically, for [this page](http://matthewpiatetsky.com/jetstrap-project/screen-04715a0e2d.html), I want to change what dorms are shown based on what dorm category is selected.
I know this can probably be done with pure html or javascript or jquery but not sure how.

Comment: This is a good starting point. I wanted to achieve the same thing a couple of months ago. Again, only a starting point utilizing pure html and javascript/jquery:

[Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605601/dynamically-change-selectbox-options-based-on-previous-option-selection)

Comment: Pure html/js is a big hole of security. I make your head turn upside down to debug if I use chrome's inspector to change the form values.

Comment: well i'm just doing a very small project to practice some things like design/databases its not a real system that needs to be robust/secure

Answer (score 0):

Put the dorm types dropdown in a  called 'foo'. Catch the onChange event for the category dropdown, rewrite the contents of the 'foo'  to contain a dropdown with the relevant options.