# select box filling out the same select box

Tags: javascript, onclick, drop-down-menu

I need to make a site, but I'm stuck... cause I only really know how to work with php and html...
trough research I understood that it's impossible to do this without javascript because php only does pre-processing...

my problem:
I want the user to be able to click on a option in the select box and that the chosen option changes the next select box.
meaning: my first select box gets filled by information from my database... depending on the choice made in the first select box the second select box needs be filled with new variabels which he also gets from the database. and the choice in the second makes the options in the third and so on.

I need this cause my database is a tree...
meaning: I have categories (which I would post in the first select box) and only giving the sub categories of the chosen categorie in the second select box and so on...

the use of this:
the user needs to be able to add a new object in the database trough selecting where he wants it and clicking on the +-button to tell me where he wants to add it... the user isn't bound to get down the whole tree and should be able to add an object in the categories, subcategories or even further on...

I hope my explaination makes sence =s so that someone can help me, cause I really don't get javascript at all =s I already searched for 1week and yet I haven't found anything... It's pretty hard searching for something where you don't know the name for... so please somebody help. thx in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically change selectbox options based on previous option selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605601/dynamically-change-selectbox-options-based-on-previous-option-selection)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery and do an ajax request whenever your select box is changed, something like

```
$(function(){
    $('input#theDropDown').change(function(){
        var theValue = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({  
           type: "GET",   
           url: "getData.php",  
           data: "TheValue=" + theValue,   
           success: function(response) { 
              // I would think 'response' would be a json string or something which contains the values the next dropdown should have
           }
    });
});
```

Where the dropdown is an input element with id=theDropDown.

Here's more info:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/